# Excitation of $n$ inhomogenous two-level atom with different detunings? Bloch sphere

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, atomic-physics, laser, two-level-system

I am learning about the bloch sphere and how it is used to to in two level systems. I have done some research already but I am slightly confused.

Suppose you have an $n$ number of inhomogenous atoms with different detunings and therefore different rabi frequencies, how could you use a combination of pulses to excite all the atoms.

I know one solution is known as "spin-echo" where you carry out a $\pi/2$ pulse, wait some time $T$, carry out a pi pulse and wait the same time $T$ at which point the bloch vectors will line up. With them lined up again, another $\pi/2$ pulse will send them to an excited state.

Is there another method of doing this where you do not have to wait a time $T$ and can send consecutive pulses to excite all $n$ atoms?

Comment: _"Suppose you have an n number of inhomogenous atoms with different detunings and therefore different rabi frequencies..."_ Rabi frequency typically refers to the frequency of rotations about the x or y axis of the Bloch sphere when the atom is subject to a continuous drive. The Rabi frequency depends on the strength of the drive and the detuning between the transition frequency and the drive frequency. The spin echo you described involves rotation about the z axis in the absence of a drive (i.e. following a pi/2 pulse as you say).

Comment: In your description it sounds like you can apply a $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ pulse on all atoms. So what stops you from applying a $\pi$ pulse?

Comment: @DanielSank so in the case where there is a drive, the atoms have different Rabi frequencies(from different detunings) is the rotation of the Z axis changed? If the atoms have different detunings is it possible to excite all the atoms to the upper state by pulsing the beam in some configuration? I'm assuming a simple Pi pulse wouldn't excite all of them because of the different detunings but I'm unsure why.

Comment: Have you tried just doing the math?